# Three classes linked to each other

Tags: c++, class, objective-c++

Kelvin.h

```
class CelciusDeg;
class FarenheitDeg;

class Kelvin
{
    double val;
public:
    friend void show(const Kelvin&);
    friend void CelciusDeg::count(const Kelvin&);
    friend void FarenheitDeg::count(const Kelvin&);
    void count(const CelciusDeg&);
    void count(const FarenheitDeg&);
    Kelvin();
    Kelvin(double);
    ~Kelvin();
};
```

CelciusDeg.h

```
class Kelvin;
class FarenheitDeg;

class CelciusDeg
{
    double val;
public:
    friend void show(const CelciusDeg&);
    friend void Kelvin::count(const CelciusDeg&);
    friend void FarenheitDeg::count(const CelciusDeg&);
    void count(const Kelvin&);
    void count(const FarenheitDeg&);
    CelciusDeg();
    CelciusDeg(double);
    ~CelciusDeg();
};
```

FarenheitDeg.h

```
class CelciusDeg;
class Kelvin;

class FarenheitDeg
{
    double val;
public:
    friend void show(const FarenheitDeg&);
    friend void Kelvin::count(const FarenheitDeg&);
    friend void CelciusDeg::count(const FarenheitDeg&);
    void count(const CelciusDeg&);
    void count(const Kelvin&);
    FarenheitDeg();
    FarenheitDeg(double);
    ~FarenheitDeg();
};
```

I am trying to make a program what can store temp values in 3 different types of temperature objects and count them to each other. How to make count method work using forward declaration ?

Comment: I would just make a single class called `Temperature` and have three separate member variables for each type of temperature scale. And each time one of the setter functions is called (e.g. `setCelcius`), you could just have the class calculate what the other two are after Celcius is set.

Comment: The class definition needs to be visible to the compiler in order to declare any of its member functions as a friend of another class.   As such, your approach has no solution, since you want each of your three classes to have friends that are members of the other classes.     Note:   it is not necessary to use separate classes to represent different temperature scales, since there is a fixed mapping from any temperature scale to another.

Comment: I am learning and it's my exercise so I need to do 3 separate classes and use friend methods and functions

Comment: What do you mean by "count"?

Comment: Take value of parameter object convert it to other scale and save to this scale object

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can call the non-default constructor and plug it in to both of the friends' functions

Comment: Yes but the friends functions won't work without including their classes and if I include them to every headers file I'll get in to include loop

Answer (score 0):

Hello I would have done a different design :

```
class Kelvin
{
   double val;

public :
   explicit Kelvin(double val);
   double getVal() const;
};

class Farenheit
{
   double val;

public :
   explicit Farenheit(double val);
   double getVal() const;
};

class Celcius
{
   double val;

public :
   explicit Celcius(double val);
   double getVal() const;
};

Kelvin toKelvin(Farenheit & o);
Kelvin toKelvin(Celcius & o);

Celcius toCelcius(Farenheit & o);
Celcius toCelcius(Kelvin & o);

Farenheit toFarenheit(Kelvin & o);
Farenheit toFarenheit(Celcius & o);
```

Comment: I had to do every class in other cpp and .h file so i've done it like this



 `friend class FarenheitDeg;
 friend class CelciusDeg;`

full class friend declaration in all header files instead of just methods.